# Simple Lambda Calculus Question

Tags: lambda-calculus, typed-lambda-calculus, normalization

For any 2 strongly normalizing terms in the simply typed Lambda Calculus, s and t, is st also strongly normalizing? And why? I'm a bit confused as this is used in a proof regarding strong normalization and the typable lambda calculus, but I have not been able to show that this is the case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the untyped λ-calculus, this is is of course not the case. The self-application term λx.xx is SN but applied to itself this gives the canonical non-terminating term. But given what you write, I wonder whether you ask about this property for the simply typed λ-calculus? It has the property but this is not how the proof of SN for it proceeds. Could you clarify?

Comment: Yes actually, that is correct - for typable Lambda Calculus terms, how do you prove application preserves the strongly normalizing property?

Comment: Proving that  application preserves SN is the hard part. Given the exact correspondence between type theories and logics know as *Curry-Howard correspondence*, this must be hard by Gödel's 2nd incompleteness theorem. The standard technique used in SN proofs is called *reducibility candidates*. Maybe https://people.mpi-sws.org/~dg/teaching/pt2012/gallier.pdf is a place to look?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/52349/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/156607/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Oh hey I wrote something on this almost 8 years ago! https://mathoverflow.net/a/206529/36103